# Event Driven Architecture Email Tracking

Tags: microservices, amazon-ses, spring-transactions

I have the below series of transaction in one of my microservice

1. sending email
2. updating the email sent status to client
3. saving the email message id info in database.

The whole transaction is event driven.
If step 3 fails, that should be retried, since email is already delivered, but need to ensure the informations are updated in db later.

Whats the general recommendation, should I initiate another transaction for db failure and keep it in a broker for retry later?

I will receiving a tracking info from SNS later, if the message id is not in db (initial transaction failed), the tracking update as well fails.